# Elasticsearch slow results with IN query and Scoring

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have text document data (500k approximately) saved in elasticsearch where the document text is mapped with it's corresponding document number.

I am trying to fetch results in batches for "***Sample Text***" in particular set of document numbers (300k appoximately) with scoring and i am facing extreme slowness in the result.

Here is the the Mapping

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings" : {
        "doc_repo" : {
            "properties" : {
                "doc_number" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                },
                "document" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets_payloads"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the request query

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "document" : [
                            "sample text"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "doc_number" : [1,2,3....,300K] //ArrayOf_300K_DocNumbers
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields" : [
        "doc_number"
    ],
    "size" : 500,
    "from" : 0
}
```

I Tried fetching result in two other ways

- Result without scoring in particular set of document numbers(i used filtering for this)
- Result with scoring but without any particular set of document numbers (in batches)

Both of these were pretty quick, but problem comes when i am trying achieve both.

Do i need to change mapping or search query or any other ways to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was specifically with elasticsearch 2.X, Upgrading elasticsearch solves the issue.